# jQuery $(document).ready suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to ask about sudden stop of jQuery. Originally I used `$(function(){ ... })` but it just stopped working, even though jQuery still works inside of angularjs functions. I tried rewriting it as `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` but it still isn't working.

Any idea of how to fix that?

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Comment: have you included jquery liberary..if yes then share console error

Comment: thousands of explainations if you don't provide more informations... (html code, js, etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use the Developer Tools (F12) within your browser to check the Console and Network tabs to see if any errors are present or if any 404s are popping up due to your jQuery library not being able to be accessed properly.

This could easily be caused if you are loading the files from a CDN and there is an issue with your connection (or the CDN). Additionally, you'll want to ensure that you aren't calling your `$(document).ready({...});` call until after your jQuery `<script>` file has been referenced